# how to make a link in a premade jquery gallery to look like a photo?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a problem with the first  link in this code, and it represents the thumbnail for a photo, and when you click it , it will expand to a larger photo. I tried to make a jsfiddle , but i could not find the code for a premade jquery mbGallery.js, so i will try to explain what should happend :
the first  represents the thumb for a phoo and when you click it , it will expand, but i can not modify it`s aspect to be 50x50, it is showing the dimension of the original photo. So if i have 1000x1000 photo , the thumb will be 1000x1000, but i still want it to automatcally resize to a little icon with (x)x(y) , x and y < 100px ( i said this in a general form, because the foto could be wide or portrait )

html

```
<div  id="g1" class="galleryCont">
    <a class="imgThumb" src="img/activitate1/2008.jpg"></a>
    <a class="imgFull" href="img/activitate1/2008.jpg"></a>
    <div class="imgDesc">Description 01</div>

    <a class="imgThumb" src="img/activitate1/2009.jpg"></a>
    <a class="imgFull" href="img/activitate1/2009.jpg"></a>
    <div class="imgDesc">Description 02</div>

    <a class="imgThumb" src="img/activitate1/2010.jpg"></a>
    <a class="imgFull" href="img/activitate1/2010.jpg"></a>
    <div class="imgDesc">Description 02</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.galleryCont{
      display:none;
    }
```

java

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mbGallery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
            $('#g1').mbGallery({maskBgnd:'#ccc',minWidth: 50, minHeight: 50, overlayOpacity:.9,startFrom: 0,addRaster:true, printOutThumbs:true});

    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the *.imgThumb* in your CSS. Add *max-width:100px* and *max-height:100px* and then it will automaticaly resize the image. Change the pixels depending on what size
Example.

```
.imgThumb{
max-width:50px;
max-height:50px;
}

.imgFull{
 max-width:500px;
max-height:500px;
}
```